# Green and white stuff on copper pipes

Tags: plumbing, leak

This is at my mom's house, an hour away. The valve in the first photo has a slow drip and I will be replacing it. The other photo (a union?) is one of a few spots that look similar but are not currently leaking.

I know the green is oxidation. How big of a concern it is that it will leak? What about all the white flaky stuff?

Should I just replace all the valves that are solid green and/or white? Should I try to clean them off and then see what they look like first?

I'm trying to prevent an emergency trip there for another leak but also not do needless work. She is on a private well.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6):

The green stuff is cupric chloride, a byproduct of corrosion of the valve body or possible copper leachate in the water.  Either way, it's typical of water leakage where the water is of low pH.

The white stuff (sometimes feels fibrous like cotton candy) is just efflorescence.  This is from dissolved minerals in the water precipitating out as the leak drips, then dries and deposits miniscule quantities of calcium, sodium, etc on the valve body. You often see this where residual flux was left on a pipe and over time, condensation or outright leakage causes these buildups.  It's always more pronounced at joints between dissimilar metals (due to galvanism).

Wearing gloves, as copper chlorides are toxic, you can remove them with full strength vinegar or dilute muriatic acid, lemon juice or even more flux and a bristle brush.  Once it's cleaned up, repair the leak or tighten the packing gland on the valve stem.  Then when all done, just liberally apply a paste of baking soda and water. It will neutralize the flux and retard further reaction (if it's condensation related).  It would be wise to have your water tested for acidity.  If you have highly acidic water, it can cause the same problem or just dissolve pipes outright.

Comment: hey - cupric chloride is green, cuprous is white.  and cuprous is not soluble in water.  ergo, the green goo is cupric.  dont edit my post unless you know what you are talking about

Comment: PPA, for future reference, @isherwood won't see your message unless you use the at-sign with his name. Since I just did so here, maybe he'll come back and read this.

Comment: OP here, thanks! So the valve I'm replacing, don't need to clean or repair it. What about the union? Clean it off and it might be ok, or better safe thank sorry and replace?

Comment: you will need to repair it or the union if they are leaking, but if not, just clean and apply baking soda.

Comment: no - it does not show both compounds.  thats the point.  the white compound cannot be cuprous chloride due to its evolution method.  imagine if somebody posted a "connect the white wire to the neutral and a black to the line" comment and you decided to "edit it for benefit of the community"  to "connect the white wire to the neutral or the ground or  the line and the black wire to the neutral or the ground or the line".  it would be factually inaccurate and could lead someone to do something harmful.  copper compounds are dangerous and should be treated as such.  confusion leads to mistakes.

Comment: Post reverted. It might be helpful to think of Stack Exchange as a community-curated wiki, where mistakes are (politely) corrected (because know one knows everything, and sometimes we don't know when we're mistaken). That's what it is, and you shouldn't take edits personally. Also, if you don't want folks messing with your posts, use capitalization and paragraphs yourself. My main goal was readability (because walls of text are hard on tired eyes), and I thought I'd add the links to help others learn. I did some learning myself.

Comment: i could honestly care less if anyone wants to edit my posts for format or grammar.  however, if you feel the need to do so, by all means proceed.  changing content though should be avoided  unless you are  sure what you are adding is correct.  i do however appreciate that anyone can make a mistake.  perhaps the best way to put it is that mistakes in chemistry related issues can sometimes lead to disastrous results, so let all make sure our facts are straight before we offer input - to questions or to answers.