# There are some green gunk near my shut off valves and my sink faucet. Do you think my water warrants for health concerns?

Tags: plumbing, water, sink, valve

I noticed some green gunk near the warm and cold water shut off valves and the sink faucet. Does the condition of my water warrant for health concerns?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Green and white stuff on copper pipes](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/86004/green-and-white-stuff-on-copper-pipes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The corrosion is on the outside of the pipe, not the inside.

It's normal green copper oxides.

It says nothing **good or bad** about your water.

It says nothing **bad or good** about your water.

If you are on a municipal supply, ask them where you can see their required test results. They might even be willing to use your tap for one of their upcoming required tests *(then again, with covid raging, they might not.)*

If you are on a private well, send a water sample out for testing. That normally involves getting a kit of sample bottles with instructions. **follow the instructions carefully** - that is normally mailed to the laboratory, and they will email or mail results to you.